# Problems after screen lock and unlock in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, firefox, lock-screen, bug-reporting

My Ubuntu 16.04 system runs fine after booting.
But if I lock the screen and unlock it again, there is some strange behavior.

First:
If you open up firefox and start typing in the addressbar, the suggestions panel is flickering for every letter I type.

Second:
If you open up nautilus and try to rename a folder, this will not be possible.

running `sudo service lightdm restart` will fix this until I lock the screen again.

Is this bug only affecting me or are there others?
Please help me filing this bug if it is relevant.

This did not happen in my previous 14.04 machine.

Comment: I see something similar, but restarting lightdm doesn't seem to fix it for me. I'm pretty sure I'm using Xubuntu 16.04. I also cannot ctrl-F1 to get to a terminal or ctrl-<backspace> to kill X, so I'm pretty much stuck doing a hard reboot.